# Fetch the row which has the Max value for two column in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, query-performance, sqlperformance

i have a table which contains id , primaryid , data ,dataname columns i want 
only rows for which contains max id and primaryid

```
create table #temp
(
    id int,
    primaryid int,
    data   nvarchar(20),
    data_name   nvarchar(30)
)


insert into #temp
values (1,1,'3223sfd','434'),(1,2,'sdfsd','dfsdfsd'),
       (1,3,'sdfs897d','898'),(1,4,'898','545'),(1,5,'898','uuyu'),
       (2,1,'3223sfd','434'),(2,2,'sdfsd','dfsdfsd'),
       (2,3,'sdfs897d','898'),(2,4,'898','545'),(2,5,'898','uuyu')
```

i achieve this with below query

```
select T.id , T.primaryid , T.data , T.data_name from #temp T , (select ID, max(primaryid) rank from #temp t2  group by id ) as T2
where t.primaryid = t2.rank group by T.id , T.primaryid , T.data , T.data_name
```

but my  table have more than 100k records  i want to worry about that

What will be optimized query for this?

Comment: Your code is not valid MySQL.  What database are you really using?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, using MSSQL but migrating code to MySQL

Comment: [_groupwise max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

Answer (score 2):

You may use `subquery` here :

```
select * 
from #temp t
where primaryid = (select max(tt.primaryid) from #temp tt where tt.id = t.id);
```

Comment: This is the best solution for the two databases.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using SQL Server.  If so, one method is:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from #temp t
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by primaryid desc);
```

Comment: you query is giving error An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'.

Comment: @NiteeshKumar... Use `order by` instead of `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

First you should create `index` on `id` and `primaryid` and then use join  as below:

```
SELECT T.id , T.primaryid , T.data , T.data_name FROM #temp T
JOIN (select id, max(primaryid) as primaryid from #temp t2  group by id ) as T2
ON T.id = t2.id and t.primaryid = t2.primaryid
```